# Web application to grab user input and create PDF

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, pdf

I am creating a web application that users can upload clients information and it will streamline a finalized professional drafted pdf document.

The document will have set static text, but it also needs to grab the clients answers they provide and combine this information into the final document.

I can handle the php, javascript, css, html and server side but I have no clue how to pull the information provided and add it to a document and create the pdf.... Please help

Here is the full picture in case I have not explain my needs above clearly.
In our business we have to create loss run request to send to carriers.  The request form is like any structured document... heading, subject, body paragraph, and signature at the bottom.
I want to have a set template that includes all the static document words. 
There will be about 5 areas that will need to pull information that the user provided. The text must then go to the document, with same style, text, font, size etc.. And automatically create the pdf on request.

Comment: Take a look at the [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) library class. There's documentation on how to use it. It's very easy and it allowes you to build professional looking PDF files exactly the way you want.

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use a html `<form>`(you can learn more about those [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_forms.htm) for example) if i understand your question correctly. Then you can use the informations provided to create your PDF file via a library like [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF) for example, which should be quite easy. Keep in mind though that jsPDF is a client side library (a javascript one in this case), which means that everything will be executed by your users'browser. If you want a server side approach, with PHP for example which can give you more options, you should probably use FPDF as suggested by icecub in the comments.

Comment: Thank you sir!  I will look into jsPDF.

Comment: @TylerPowell Remember that jsPDF is a Javascript library. This means that the information filled in by your visitor and the PDF files aren't saved on the server unless you code those parts yourself!

Comment: @icecub Thank you for the precision, i might not have been very clear indeed.

Comment: @TheoSardin No problem. That's why I prefer to use FPDF. It's a PHP library and therefor serverside. Makes it a lot easier when you actually need to keep the information yourself as well.

Comment: @TheoSardin May I suggest you edit your answer with some explanation about the differences between a client side library like jsPDF and a server side library like FPDF (include both libraries in your answer). I'll give you an upvote if you do that as it would clearly improve your answer :)